# How to use custom jQuery in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been thinking about this for a couple of days already.

For some reason my semantic-ui jQuery doesn't work.

So here's what I did.

On my webpack/environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

I added a custom.js file with the following codes under app/javascripts/packs:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
})
```

And then inside of my application.js w/c is under app/javascripts/packs I have the ff:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("packs/custom")
```

On chrome console here's what I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4588)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4408)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
```

I thought I did it right but for some reason this solution did not work at all.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would guess that the jQuery plugin that supplies the dropdown method has not been initialized at the time you call `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()`.

Answer (score 5):

Look my `/confog/webpack/environment.js` file like below:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

And `/app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
require("jquery")
require("bootstrap")
require("packs/custom") // Here is my custom jQuery file like packs/custom.js
```

and in the `/packs/custom.js` look like for jQuery preloader

```
// Preloader JS
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut();
});
```

and exactly this way, custom jQuery is working nicely.

My project based on `bootstrap 4` so I run this command for installing dependencies

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

I think it will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
yarn add jquery
```

in packs/application.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Answer (score 0):

On my webpack/environment.js:

```
 module.exports = environment
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

And /app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("jquery")              //add this in application.js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

run this command for installing dependencies

```
  "yarn add jquery"
```