# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function in rails 6

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, ruby-2.4

Getting this error in rails 6, in rails 5 it was a easy fix after updating the application to rails 6, including webpack this error is appear every where I try to close the model inside the js.erb files.

My files: pack/application.rb

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap";
import "./src/application.scss";
import "jquery"
```

file pack/src/application.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

file config/webpack/environment.js

```
   const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

    const webpack = require('webpack')
    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
        })
    )
    module.exports = environment
```

Comment: I think maintain both Jquery via webpacker and the traditional way like we do in Rals 5 and 4 is the solution by using gems.

Comment: Hi @vidur, Just wondering if you ever got this resolved using Rails 6 and webpacker?

Comment: Got the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: link = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376431/how-to-use-custom-jquery-in-rails-6/61815188#61815188

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: [enter link description here][1]
Change your environment.js to

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

)

Two Jquerys was being loaded twice, on
[1]: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/webpacker-bootstrap-jquery-what-am-i-doing-wrong-and-why-so-hard/77105/4?u=chibeepatag