# Rails 6 + webpack error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, popover, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm starting a new project in rails 6 and it's going to be my first experience with Webpack, I'm having problems using the **popover**, **tooltip**, **dropdown**.

> application.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a
> function

**environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        Rails: ['@rails/ujs']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

**application.js**

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("channels")

import 'bootstrap'
import './menu-left.cleanui-custom'
import './menu-right.cleanui-custom'
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

import '../stylesheets/application'


document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    $('[data-toggle=popover-hover]').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: false
    });
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: false
    });
});

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Where can the mistake come from? The truth is I'm still pretty lost with webpack.

Comment: `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` this line is causing the error, it could be caused by not targeting the html element correctly, or that the `dropdown()` function isn't valid (either spell/cased incorrectly, or it's not being loaded). I would try going into the browsers inspect console and seeing if `$('.dropdown-toggle')` actually targets the element you're expecting and go from there.

Comment: @SomeSchmo The elements are on the page. Using sprocket works fine so I think it's about the way to include the js.

Comment: Have a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376431/how-to-use-custom-jquery-in-rails-6. It fixed my issue with bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
environment.config.merge(
  module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
      }
    }
  }
)

module.exports = environment
```

`app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
import "jquery"
import 'bootstrap'

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code `/config/webpack/environment.js` file like below:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

And `/app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("jquery");
require("bootstrap");
```

By setting these configurations I was able to resolve the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(…).popover is not a function`

For adding bootstrap 4, jQuery and popper.js I used the command below

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```